# MS Office color scheme not applying to custom form in Outlook Plugin

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-office

I'm working on an Outlook plugin that brings up a custom form.  If I change Outlook 2007's color scheme by going to Tools>Options>Mail Format>Editor Options and change the color, it applies to everything in Outlook except my custom form.

How can I determine Office's color scheme programatically and apply it to my form?